# Creating DataAdapters for Entity Framework

Tags: .net, entity-framework, data-binding, dataadapter, xtrareport

This relates to the reporting suite we are using, but I believe the pattern is the same for WinForms and other .NET technologies.

The reporting suite we are using (XtraReports 10) supports design time preview of the data if the DataAdapter property is set. When using a DataSet datasource, a TableAdapter is generated (by the DataSet), which can be assigned to the DataAdapter property of the report (or the BindingSource)

How can I get the equivalent to the TableAdapter when I am using the Entity Framework?

Visual Studio 2010 (.NET 4.0)

Rob